# Disable supplementary view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

What is the correct of of disabling the supplementary views (e.g. header)? One time I want to show them (iPhone) and one time I don't want to show them (iPad).

The only idea I currently have is to return a size of zero in `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`. But I think it's kind of an overhead to create views, which aren't used at all. On the other side I have to implement `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` and I can't return `nil`, because the app crashes then.

How can I disable the supplementary views in `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return `CGSizeZero` from `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` delegate method `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Developer API Reference states about [`collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617702-collectionview):

> If the size in the appropriate scrolling dimension is 0, no header is added.

---

The following Swift 5 code snippet shows a possible implementation of `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` in order to display or not `UICollectionView` supplementary views:

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
        return CGSize.zero
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 40)
        // or
        //let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        //return flowLayout.headerReferenceSize
    }
}
```